# C# EntryPointNotFoundException Unable to find an entry point named 'SetDllDirectory' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'

Tags: c#, dll, kernel32

I am trying to use several functions from kernal32.dll.  However, when my application tries to call the first function it throws an EntryPointNotFoundException `Unable to find an entry point named 'SetDllDirectory' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'.`

```
public class MyClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use to interface to kernel32.dll for dynamic loading of similar DLLs.
    /// </summary>
    internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);
    }

    private void MyFunc()
    {
        if (UnsafeNativeMethods.SetDllDirectory(_location) == false) // <-- Exception thrown here.
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(_location);
        }

        /* Some code. */

        _dllHandle = UnsafeNativeMethods.LoadLibrary(_fullPath);

        /* Some more code. */

        _fptr = UnsafeNativeMethods.GetProcAddress(_dllHandle, _procName);

        /* Yet even more code. */
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong and how I can get it working would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to remove the ExactSpelling property.  The real name of the function is SetDllDirectoryW.  I also recommend you use CharSet.Auto, using Ansi is a lossy conversion that can cause subtle problems.  The export is not available in any Windows version prior to XP SP1.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about `DllImport`, but on my machine removing `ExactSpelling` attribute just do it.